# Cannot get Remove From Current Selection to work in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, select, select-by-location

I am a Newbie using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop:

1. After importing a whole watershed streams Layer, I selected by location a subset of the streams which was already defined with a separate name. "intersect the layer feature", thus the subset streams become highlighted
2. To take out a piece of the selected subset I did the following:

   - got closet to the area to be extracted using the + zoom tool
   - activated the "select features" button for an interactive selection
   - ensured that only one layer become affected by the changes: 
     Table of Contents, Make This The Only Selectable Layer, 
     -Then: Selection, Make This the Only Selectable Layer
   - Then: Selection, Remove From Current Selection
   - clicked and dragged small box over a part of the feature... and there was no extraction.
     What did happen was that the subset lost its highlighted status which depicted the streams that were related with the larger watershed.

Comment: How many layers do you  have in your table of contents? Also, can you post a screen shot of your current ArcMap TOC and canvass.

Answer (score 2):

Your steps above listed appear that you are on the right track and are following a sound method to select the features of your interest.

I would suggest to follow the steps once more as you outlined, ensuring that you in fact specified the correct layer "Make This the Only Selectable Layer". It can be that you in fact didn't select the particular layer you wanted to. This is further confirmed in my mind by your statement:

> clicked and dragged small box over a part of the feature... and there was no extraction. What did happen was that the subset lost its highlighted status which depicted the streams that were related with the larger watershed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to top menu: selection/select by location
2. Make the feature set you want modified be the *target layer.  (If you're working on the project I'm suspecting you are working on, NHDFlowline).
3. spatial selection method in dialog should be "intersect the source feature"
   (if you're working on project I'm guessing, source is navarro_boundary)
4. select ok.
   selection should be light blue (or could be another color if configured to another color). that will confirm you have the feature selected so you can edit it.
   Then the steps you said you were pursuing should work. Only last thing you could double check is selections/selection options that the top radio button is selected ("Select features partially...")

Answer (score 0):

You have to click the "Select Features" tool first.